# PHP : Count GROUP BY Results

Tags: php, sql, count, group-by

I have a query that attempts to group the same values. What I am having trouble with is counting the number of rows for each group. my code is below but it doesn't seem to work the COUNT(*) just outputs  (1)

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
<?
$sql_inv = mysql_query("SELECT * ,COUNT(*) FROM I WHERE id = '$I_1_id' OR id = '$I_2_id' OR id = '$I_3_id' OR id = '$I_4_id' OR id = '$I_5_id' OR id = '$I_6_id' OR id = '$I_7_id' OR id = '$I_8_id' OR id = '$I_9_id' OR id = '$I_10_id' OR id = '$I_11_id' OR id = '$I_12_id' OR id = '$I_13_id' OR id = '$I_14_id' OR id = '$I_15_id' OR id = '$I_16_id' OR id = '$I_17_id' OR id = '$I_18_id' OR id = '$I_19_id' OR id = '$I_20' GROUP BY id");

$inv_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql_inv);
    while ($row_inv = mysql_fetch_array($sql_inv)){
        echo $row_inv['I_Type'];
        echo ' : ';
        echo $row_inv['I_Model'];
        echo ' (';
        echo $row_inv['COUNT(*)'];
        echo ')';
            if ($inv_num_rows >= 2) {
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think you don't need to Group By Id, but just "ORDER BY id". See if that works.

Comment: that will select each row from I matching any of those IDs.  That's not the desired result.

Comment: ORDER BY Produces only 1 result

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is the ID of a shopping list, and you want to count number of times each I_Type and I_Model combination occurs for each ID, what oyu'd want to do is GROUP BY all 3.

```
SELECT *, count(*) AS duplicates FROM I GROUP BY I_Model, I_Type, id;
```

It really does work if the data is actually the same based on the fields specified in `GROUP BY`.  An example with a bit more schem built up would look like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4c47/1

Instead of saying constructs like `WHERE id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3 or id =4 or id = 5` try an `IN` clause such as `WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5)`.  It's a lot easier to read and write.

Comment: I was grouping by id because the variables $I_1 is an id from the "I" database. So I have a database of 300 "products" I then create a "Shopping list" and that is saved in a "S" database and have 20 fields I can than choose the product, basically i just need to see if someone chose the same product twice, or 20 time.

Comment: tried the above fix and it still only shows (1) for the counts

Comment: can you make an example in SQLFiddle?

Comment: @user3076667, in your example each model and type are unique.  The whole point of Group is that you're combining rows that are equal in the fields of the GROUP BY.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1595c/5 - I made some duplicates so the count showed, and removed the IDs so you could see how GROUP BY works.

Comment: yes like I said, each product(Type, Model) is unique but the shopping list might contain that product in any one(or more) of 20 spots on the list. I'm trying to determine and count if the product shows up more than once. so in the SQlfiddle I showed the "Shopping list"(which refers to the id number of the product in the product database) in the WHERE clause in my sql.

Comment: in this SQLfiddle i call out the "shopping list" fields in the WHERE id IN() clause. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e294f/8

Comment: Oh, starting to understand.  Your example is really denormalized ( a shopping list table with 6 columns?  ) but I think I see what you're going for.  You simply need to GROUP BY all 3.  eg, `GROUP BY list_id, item_model, item_type `.    A more normalized example of this kind of schema would look like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4c47/1